# Looping through an xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I have two questions regarding reading data from a file in .xlsx format.

1. Is it possible to convert an .xlsx file to .csv without actually opening the file in pandas or using xlrd? Because when I have to open many files this is quite slow and I was trying to speed it up.
2. Is it possible to use some sort of for loop to loop through decoded xlsx lines? I put an example below.

```
xlsx_file = 'some_file.xlsx'
with open(xlsx_file) as lines:
   for line in lines:
       <do something like I would do for a normal string>
```

I would like to know if this is possible without the well known xlrd module.

Comment: The short answer to your last question is no.  If you are dealing with data from Excel, either convince the user to save it from Excel in csv format, or use xlrd, or effectively rewrite xlrd yourself.

Comment: @ Alan Hoover Okay, thanks! That's clear.